# Rails - Morris chart not appearing

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, morris.js

I am a newbie in Rails and trying to develop the front-end of my own project currently.

I would like to use MorrisJs to display charts, so I used the "morrisjs-rails" and "raphael-rails" gems and require morris and raphael in the application.js file.

Then, I try to follow the tutorial from railscast: [(Youtube Link Here)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yBMQTi_SjfU), I copied the example code from morrisjs official website and translated it to CoffeeScript by js2coffee2.0 and create a file called `chart.js.coffee` under `application/assets/javascripts`. Also, added an element in my html file - `<div id="myfirstchart" style="height: 150px;"></div>`

However, it did not show the chart, but just a blank area, and came out an error saying: Uncaught error: Graph container element not found.

So, I found a potential solution from [tiraeth](https://github.com/morrisjs/morris.js/issues/137), saying that

> JavaScript's code gets executed before the DOM contains #annual
>   element. Put the javascript after the div or use jQuery.ready().

So, how could I put the javascript after the content of page? I am confused about whether the asset pipeline allow me to do this or not.

Moreover, I've seen that the railscast tutorial did display the morris chart appropriately without messing up with the applicaiton.js file, but simply adding //= require morris and //= require raphael into it. I wonder why I can't get it display appropriately while doing the same thing?

FYI, my application.js is like

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
.. require something else ..
//= require raphael
//= require morris
//= require_tree .
```

**Update**
The following is the code of my `chart.js.coffee`. It doesn't get the uncaught error, but still showing a blank area.

```
  $ ->
  new (Morris.Line)(
    element: 'myfirstchart'
    data: [
      {
        year: '2008'
        value: 20
      }
      {
        year: '2009'
        value: 10
      }
      {
        year: '2010'
        value: 5
      }
      {
        year: '2011'
        value: 5
      }
      {
        year: '2012'
        value: 20
      }
    ]
    xkey: 'year'
    ykeys: [ 'value' ]
    labels: [ 'Value' ])
  return
```

Thanks for reading my questions, and appreciate any opinions and suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wait for the DOM to load before calling the chart, the container element won't exist. You need to wrap the code in chart.js in document ready tags. If you're using jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // code goes here...
});
```

Or coffeescript:

```
$ ->
  # code goes here...
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have tried to add the .ready() method but with no luck. It doesn't get the uncaught error, but still display a black area. Please see my update.